# Ruby 1.9 thread pools

Tags: ruby, multithreading, threadpool

As I understand, Ruby 1.9 uses OS threads but only one thread will still actually be running concurrently (though one thread may be doing blocking IO while another thread is doing processing). The threading examples I've seen just use `Thread.new` to launch a new thread. Coming from a Java background, I typically use thread pools as to not launch to many new threads since they are "heavyweight."

Is there a thread pool construct built into ruby? I didn't see one in the default language libraries. Or are there is a standard gem that is typically used? Since OS level threading is a newer feature of ruby, I don't know how mature the libraries are for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct in that the default C Ruby interpreter only executes one thread at a time (other C based dynamic languages such as Python have similar restrictions). Because of this restriction, threading is not really that common in Ruby and as a result there is no default threadpool library. If there are tasks to be done in parallel, people typically uses processes  since processes can scale over multiple servers.

If you do need to use threads, I would recommend you use https://github.com/meh/ruby-threadpool on the JRuby platform, which is a Ruby interpreter running on the JVM. That should be right up your alley, and because it is running on the virtual machine it will have true threading.

Comment: Thanks. I don't actually have a use case right now, but as I was reading the pickaxe book, this was something I was unsure of, but you have clarified.

Comment: I don't understand while people mention that threads are useless in Ruby because they are not running concurrently. They are indeed useless for CPU bound tasks but they can be very useful for any blocking IO that you want to do in parallel. Eg. concurrent HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I need to further clarify that threads are not useless in Ruby, just that people need to be aware of the limitation of the GIL since threads are not without overhead.  For non-blocking IO, an event C based asynchronous call may be more appropriate. See http://blog.gregweber.info/posts/2011-06-16-high-performance-rb-part3 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, But, there are many tasks in which threads are fine. after all there are some reasons why it is there. even though it can only run a thread at a time. it is still can be considered parallel in many real life situations.

for example when we have 100  long running process in which each takes approximate 10 minutes to complete. by using threads in ruby, even with all those restrictions, if we define a threadpool of 10 tasks at time, it will run much faster than 100*10 minutes when running without threads. examples include, live capturing of file changes, sending large number of web requests (such as status check)

You can understand how pooling works by reading https://blog.codeship.com/understanding-fundamental-ruby-abstraction-concurrency/ . in production code use https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread#pool